# Ruby on Rails 4 - structuring database with nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having considerable trouble setting up my database using nested attributes, and even after many hours of googling I can't find an answer. Should I keep trying to fix this, or start over because my idea for how to structure my database is somehow wrong?

My structure is:

Questions (questions that will be asked in a wizard, presented depending on answers to previous questions)

Responses (possible answers to questions, user_input will save user's input to response (e.g. a particular number) in connection with a particular experiment)

Experiment (the thing the wizard is assembling)

User (has multiple experiments, each a separate run of the wizard)

Example seed:

```
    Question.create(
 {
  :title => 'rm power analysis 2',
  :content => 'Look up what the next step should be. Maybe just display result of power analysis.', 
  :responses_attributes => [
    { content: 'Seperate measurements per subject:', input_type: 'number 2 20', next_question: 'rm power analysis 2'}, 
    { content: 'Seperate measurements per subject:', input_type: 'number 2 20', next_question: 'rm power analysis 2'},
    { content: 'unsure', input_type: 'radio', next_question: 'rm power analysis 2' }
  ], 
  :tell_me_more => 'lengthy explanation text goes here.'
 }
) 

class CreateQuestions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :questions do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :content
      t.has_many :responses
      t.has_many :experiments, through: :responses
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class AddTellMeMoreToQuestions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :questions, :tell_me_more, :text
  end
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base

  # ownerships
  has_many :responses, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :responses 
end
```

Other classes

```
class Experiment < ActiveRecord::Base
#ownerships
has_many :responses
accepts_nested_attributes_for :responses, :reject_if => lambda { |a|   a[:content].blank? }
has_many :questions, :through => :responses
belongs_to :user

  def current_question
    @current_question || questions.first
  end

end

class Response < ActiveRecord::Base

  # ownerships
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :experiment
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Ownerships
  has_many :experiments, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :experiments, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
  has_many :responses, :through => :experiments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :responses, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
  ...
end
```

[image: attempt at UML structure]

Comment: Maybe it would be better you let us know the design of your database tables and relations: E/R, UML or simple description. Then we can help better. Otherwise people would just answer based on the code, which might not be desirable.